# Xpath query contains

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the folowing code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$query = '/root/parent[Model="Corolla"]';

//RUN QUERY ON XML
$xQuery = $xml->xpath($query);
```

And here is the XML file:

```
<root>
   <parent>
     <Model>Corolla A/C</Model>
   </parent>
</root>
```

This code works good if I'm searching for the exact string "Corolla". The problem I'm having is that some of the values are similar to "Corolla A/C good condition"

Is there a way I can query the XML file for any Model element that contains the word Corolla rather then the exact string Corolla?

EDIT: I added an example of my XML help clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case I would suggest the `starts-with` function rather than `contains` (given the assumption all your models begin with the word "Corolla"):

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, you would have to change the query to:

```
/root/parent/Model[starts-with(., 'Corolla')]
```

You may also have a look at the [Zvon XSLT Tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/example46_ch12.html). It's a very nice read.

Comment: I just edited the original post to show an example of what my XML file might look like. When using the @Model, will it work with the example I've shown? Because the corolla is entered as a value not an attribute if I'm not mistaken. Thanks for the help I will bookmark this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
/root/parent[contains(@Model, 'Corolla')]
```

Note the `@` on the Model... that's necessary to indicate that you're working with an attribute of the `parent` tag, and not some OTHER tag whose name happens to be `Model`.